# UIPopoverView gets rendered only partly

Tags: ios

My App in the Apple AppStore has a UIPopoverView which gets rendered only partly. It appears only half on the screen as shown in the screen snapshot.
It appears this way by only a few customers of the app and not on any of my test devices.

I have no idea why this happens.

[image: Screen snapshot here]

Here is the soucrecode:

```
#import "TripsTableViewController.h"
#import "Database+Trip.h"
#import "Utils.h"
#import "TripAnnotationLayer.h"
#import "TripPointsTableViewController.h"
#import "TripsSortCell.h"

#define dumpTrips()  NSLog(@"Trips: %@", [trips description])

@interface TripsTableViewController () {
    NSArray *trips;
    NSInteger sortSegment;
}

@end

@implementation TripsTableViewController

@synthesize mapView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.allowsSelectionDuringEditing = YES;
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    sortSegment = 0;
}

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    [self reloadTrips];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}    

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    return 2;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    return indexPath.section!=0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    if (section==0) return 1;
    return [trips count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        TripsSortCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TripsSortCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[TripsSortCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"TripsSortCell"];
        }
        cell.tripsTableViewController = self;
        [cell.sortSegment setSelectedSegmentIndex:sortSegment];
        return cell;
    } else {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TripsCell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
        NSArray *row = trips[indexPath.row];
        NSString *name = row[1];
        cell.textLabel.text = name;
        NSInteger tripID = [row[0] integerValue];
        double tripLength = [[Database sharedInstance] getTripLength:tripID];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [Utils getDistanceAsString:tripLength forKey:@"distance"];
        cell.tag = tripID;

        return cell;
    }
}

- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TripPoints"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
        NSInteger tripID = cell.tag;
        TripPointsTableViewController *target = (TripPointsTableViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        target.tripID = tripID;
        target.mapView = mapView;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        NSInteger tripID = [trips[indexPath.row][0] integerValue];
        [[Database sharedInstance] removeTrip:tripID];
        trips = [[Database sharedInstance] getTrips];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        if ([trips count] == 0) {
            [[Database sharedInstance] createTripWithName:@"trip"];
            [self reloadTrips];
        }
        NSInteger newTripID = [trips[0][0] integerValue];
        [self setSelectedTripID:newTripID];
    }
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    if (indexPath.section==0) return;
    NSInteger newTripID = [trips[indexPath.row][0] integerValue];
    [self setSelectedTripID:newTripID];
    self.mapView.tripsAnnotationLayer.visible = YES;
}

- (IBAction)addTrip:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    [[Database sharedInstance] createTripWithName:@"trip"];
    [self reloadTrips];
}

- (void) setSelectedTripID:(NSInteger) newTripID {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    self.mapView.tripsAnnotationLayer.tripID = newTripID;

    NSArray *trippoints = [[Database sharedInstance] getTripPointsOfTrip:newTripID];
    if ([trippoints count]>0) {
        NSArray *row = trippoints[0];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;
        coordinate.latitude = [row[2] doubleValue];
        coordinate.longitude = [row[3] doubleValue];

        double zoomLimit = 8.999;
        if (mapView.visibleTileSource>1)
            zoomLimit = 14.0;

        if (mapView.zoom >= zoomLimit) {
            [mapView setCenterCoordinate:coordinate animated:NO];
        } else {
            [mapView setZoom:zoomLimit atCoordinate:coordinate animated:NO];
        }

    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();

    NSString *sectionName;
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Sort", @"Sort");
            break;
        case 1:
            sectionName = NSLocalizedString(@"Trips", @"Trips");
            break;
        default:
            sectionName = @"";
            break;
    }
    return sectionName;
}

- (void) onSortSegment:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    sortSegment = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
    [self reloadTrips];
}

- (void) reloadTrips {
    LogMethod();
    dumpTrips();
    trips = [[Database sharedInstance] getTrips];
    trips = [trips sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
        NSArray *trip1 = obj1;
        NSArray *trip2 = obj2;

        if (sortSegment==0) {
            NSInteger trip1ID =[trip1[0] integerValue];
            NSInteger trip2ID =[trip2[0] integerValue];
            if (trip1ID>trip2ID) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if (trip1ID<trip2ID) {
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            } else {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }
        } else if (sortSegment==1) {
            NSString *name1 = trip1[1];
            NSString *name2 = trip2[1];

            return [name1 compare:name2 options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        } else if (sortSegment==2) {
            NSInteger trip1ID =[trip1[0] integerValue];
            NSInteger trip2ID =[trip2[0] integerValue];

            double tripLength1 = [[Database sharedInstance] getTripLength:trip1ID];
            double tripLength2 = [[Database sharedInstance] getTripLength:trip2ID];
            if (tripLength1>tripLength2) {
                return NSOrderedAscending;
            } else if (tripLength1<tripLength2) {
                return NSOrderedDescending;
            } else {
                return NSOrderedSame;
            }

        }
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

@end
```

The UIPopoverView gets shown by a storybard-segue. Inside the parent-Tableview there is only this code:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"trips"]) {
        TripsTableViewController *tripsTableViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        tripsTableViewController.mapView = [self mapView];
    }
}
```

It is part of a UINavigationViewContoller with no code in it.
I already tried to move the launch of the UIPopoverView to an extra debug-button in the toolbar which uses a non-special segue in the storyboard to launch the UIPopoverView. Same result.
As mentioned, it only appears on a few percent of devices as reported by the users of the app (Pilots Atlas). And it does not appear on any of my test-devices (about 10 different test-devices).

And for sure, alpha is not changed anywhere. See the left and right NavigationBarButtons, they already appear as the do normally.

Comment: What does your popup-making code look like? Are you doing anything out of the ordinary?

Comment: Is TripsTableViewController the contentViewController of the UIPopoverController?  How exactly is the code related to the screenshot?  Most of that code looks irrelevant and it's too much.  It might be useful instead to see how the _popover_ is created and presented.  By "rendered partly" and "half on the screen" do you mean instead that its `alpha` is not 1?